# could not change image dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change image dynamically for my responsive site. When i resize my browser, nothing happens. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

$(window).ready(function() {
var wi = $(window).width();  


$(window).resize(function() {
    var wi = $(window).width();

    if (wi <= 480){
       document.getElementsByClassName('party')[0].src="images/1.jpg"
        }
   else {
        document.getElementsByClassName('party')[0].src="images/5.jpg"
        }
});            
});
```

My html as follows:

```
<div class="party">
        <div class="dance">
          <h2 id="head">Your Party begins here</h2>
          <p id="intro1">Start dancing</p>
          <a id="starter" href="#" >Dance now</a> </div>
        <a id="main" href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/default.jpg" alt="main image"></a>
```

Comment: class `party`  is a `div`, div doesn't have src property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).ready(function() {


$(window).resize(function() {
    var wi = $(window).width();

    if (wi <= 480){
       $("#main").find("img").attr("src","images/1.jpg")
        }
   else {
       $("#main").find("img").attr("src","images/5.jpg");
        }
});            
});
```

Try this code,also you were unnecessarily declaring `wi` twice.

Comment: OMG!!! have been doing this for so long without a break! Your solution works!! Thanks a Million!

Answer (score 2):

Image element have class `img-responsive` and not `party`. also you are mixing javascript and jquery. i would rather suggest you to either use pure JS or jquery:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var wi = $(window).width();
  $('.img-responsive').attr('src',wi < = 480 ? "images/1.jpg" : "images/5.jpg");
});
```

Comment: It can be a good thing to use the native js for things all browsers support and just use the jquery parts for what you need. You do not need to stick to one or the other.

Comment: Jquery still has its use but as browser api get adopted and more powerful the need for jquery drops. If you need to do something basic to a dom element it is simple to just use the dom api. Personally i only use jquery for event binding, ajax and if i need to use a plugin of some sort. Though in the end this is only our opinion and everyone codes differently

Answer (score 0):

Just as Milind Anantwar suggests, you are attempting to set the src of the div with the "party" class. You should instead be setting the image with the class "img-responsive"'s src-attribute.

Try the plunkr below, and check the logs in the console which shows that you are in fact grabbing the wrong element in your jQuery code.

```
if (wi <= 480) {
        var partyElement = document.getElementsByClassName('party')[0];
        console.log(partyElement);
        document.getElementsByClassName('img-responsive')[0].src = "images/1.jpg"
      } else {
        var partyElement2 = document.getElementsByClassName('party')[0];
        console.log(partyElement2)
        document.getElementsByClassName('img-responsive')[0].src = "images/5.jpg"
      }
```

Heres a plunkr 
http://plnkr.co/edit/wBVt4qQZdOOrw94rHJFZ?p=preview